# Extract zip file to TStream using zlibar in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, zip, pascal, lazarus

I'm trying to extract a zip file from a `TMemoryStream` to another `TMemoryStream` using zlibar in Lazarus. From what I can tell, my code follows the examples found [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Zlibar). I am using a simple zip archive with one text file in it. The zip archive was created using PowerArchiver, nothing special. Here is my code:

```
uses
  zlibar;
var
  z, Dest: TMemoryStream;
  unZip: TZLibReadArchive;     
begin
  z := TMemoryStream.Create;
  z.LoadFromFile('kov.zip');
  unZip := TZLibReadArchive.Create(z);
  UnZip.ExtractFileToStream(0, Dest);
```

I am getting this error: "ZLibError(2) corrupt file or not a correct file type."
See zlibar.pas here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8899944/files/zlibar.pas
Any ideas why I am getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that code handles ZIP? Could easily be just a zlib library.

Comment: No, I am not. The page in my question says nothing of what kind of files it supports, although in the zlibar.pas, it mentions Z, A, and R. I don't know the significance of that.

Comment: I've had a look at the code and it's pretty clear that it doesn't support ZIP, as I suspected. You'll need to use a different library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zlibar library does not read zip files. It reads and writes a custom archive format. You can tell because the table-of-contents format described in [*zlibar.pas*](https://lazarus-ccr.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/lazarus-ccr/components/zlibar/zlibar.pas) is completely different from [the one used in zip files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#File_headers).

The [FreePascalArchivePackage](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FreePascalArchivePackage) link looks like it might someday provide what you want, although the page last had significant changes in 2007.

There's also the [ZipFile](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/ZipFile) package, which appears to come with Lazarus.

Comment: You are correct. I decided to go with [paszlib](http://wiki.freepascal.org/paszlib). It can take input from and output to a TStream using standard zip files.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess: Try to set `z.Position := 0` before `unZip := TZLibReadArchive.Create(z);`.

Comment: Then the file must be corrupted... Are you sure zlibar can handle .zip files? Or is it only for gzip files? I've never used zlibar... If you are not successful, try TPAbbrevia, it works without any problems.